# How can I move all contents of a horizontal li on a screen resize?

Tags: html, css

Question:  How can I style the li tags so that all of its contents will move on a resize?

Seteup:  I have a ASP.NET 4.0 Website Project.  It has a set of dropdowns, each with a leading label, generate by the psuedocode below.

```html
<div class="dataFilter">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        Label1:</label>
      <asp:DropDownList1 />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        Label2:
      </label>
      <asp:DropDownList2 />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        Label3:
      </label>
      <asp:DropDownList3 />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

.dataFilter h1 
{
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.dataFilter ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.dataFilter ul li 
{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: .5em;
}
```

The above code renders something like this:

**Label1** Dropdown1 **Label2** Dropdown2 **Label3** Dropdown3

Currently, when the screen is resized, each element is moved one at a time, so I get a situation where the dropdowns appear like this:

**Label1** Dropdown1 **Label2** Dropdown2 **Label3**

Dropdown3

Instead, I would like for the set of dropdowns to move both the dropdown and its corresponding label like this:

**Label1** Dropdown1 **Label2** Dropdown2
             **Label3**   Dropdown3

I cannot figure out the right combination of styles to make li contents shift as desired; the closest I got was using float: left, but that ended up floating the contents of the third li on top of the other two.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the style to this:

> display: inline-block;

```
.dataFilter ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: .5em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!  I'll try to up vote this as soon as I can, although my rep is still too low.

Comment: your welcome.... if it helped please give some credit to my answer... (+1 and mark as solution). Thanks.